# Bounty or new question?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, questions, bounty

It's been 4 years since I asked [Applying version control to ArcGIS Models](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3749/applying-version-control-to-arcgis-models).

The essence of my question for the main site is: has anything significant in the landscape changed since then? combined with recasting the Q so it targets toolboxes themselves and all components rather than just a common component (models).

**The question for meta is** : what is your opinion on whether it would be better to edit the question and offer a bounty, or to post as a new question referencing the old?

On other Stack sites my experience with offering bounties to get new information on old questions is rather dismal, so I'm leery of that, but I also tend to prefer consolidation over proliferation... I'm conflicted, help me out. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, I would say, without hesitation, that you should edit your question in such a way that it does not unduly invalidate any of the existing answers (or touch up those answers at the same time to keep them "in sync"), and consider adding a bounty, in order to draw new attention to it.

This would be in line with [Getting attention for unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions).

However, if version control on toolboxes containing models, rather than [version control on toolboxes which can be text files](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/123451/115), is your requirement, then ArcGIS Pro going into general release soon may present you with a golden opportunity to ask what you want as a new question.

I recommend that you edit your old question to have it ask explicitly about models created from the ArcMap/ArcCatalog/ArcScene/ArcGlobe architecture that pre-dates ArcGIS Pro, and ask your new question based on the changes made to ModelBuilder to bring it into the ArcGIS Pro architecture.  I am not familiar with how much changed between the two, but this is an opportunity to sound some of that out.